sei so gewollt?
In our course, the teacher asked us:
es hat euch nicht stutzig gemacht, dass da so eine krumme Zahl rauskommt?
and one of my classmates answered:  Nö, Wir dachten, das sei so gewollt.
Although I can figure out the general meaning of what my classmate wanted to say, this structure is so confusing for me. Can you please explain the grammar and meaning and provide other examples in other contexts?

Baseline is the word wollen:

Der Lehrer will, dass die Schüler auch mit "krummen" Zahlen rechnen können.

The Zustandspassiv is "gewollt sein", which means "to be intentional" or even "to be (as) desired".

Ein bisschen Muskelkater nach dieser Trainingseinheit ist durchaus gewollt.
Die Stellenanzeige ist ein wenig abschreckend, aber das ist gewollt.

Put that into Konjunktiv (for reported thoughts):

Die Schüler dachten, die Aufgabe sei so gewollt, wie sie formuliert war.
Die Schüler dachten, es sei gewollt, dass die Aufgabe so schwierig ist.

Then use it with a pronoun refering to a whole fact:

Diese Aufgabe war sehr schwierig. Das war vom Lehrer so gewollt.
Diese Aufgabe war sehr schwierig, aber die Schüler dachten, das sei so gewollt.
"Kam es Euch nicht komisch vor, dass die Aufgabe so schwierig zu rechnen war?" - "Nö, wir dachten, das sei so gewollt."

